# Univariate and multivariate outlier detection

Tags: outliers, anomaly-detection, z-score, univariate

I have a dataset with several features (about 15), and I am interested in finding outliers.

My approach is to perform univariate analysis to highlight outliers in the single features and multivariate analysis to find outliers given by the combination of them.

The major problem is that most of the features don't follow a gaussian distribution because they are very skewed (can be approximated to poisson distribution).

I've tested different approaches:

- robust z-score: usually the threshold is around 2.5, but with most of the features this was not enough and I had to increase it
- Tukey boxplot: the whiskers are usually set to [Q1 – 1.5 IQR, Q3 + 1.5 IQR].For some features I had to increase them because the number of detected outliers was too high. (I have also considered the variant for skewed distributions, the situation is better but I always have to adjust the whiskers)

Here are my questions:

- is it a acceptable procedure to manually increase the thresholds to reduce the number of outlier detected?
- given that some features are not normally distributed, which approach can be exploited to detect outliers in a multivariate analysis i.e. considering all the features together?

Thank you